# Clickable and Rotatable models using Unity and ARToolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, 3dsmax, artoolkit

Can the 3D models used with the markers be made clickable and rotate able using Unity3D engine and ARToolkit unity. Basically in the AR desktop application we are making , we want to implement this functionality on the 3D models as well. Kindly need help in this matter. ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The only issue you could find is that the Transformation of the AR Tracked Object changes based on the visual information.

If you simply use that as a base object and put any other models as children of that one, you can modify their position and rotation in the same way you would do for any other situation.

So, as you see, the Marker scene has nothing but an AR Tracked Object, this is the object that will be updated with the pose of the marker.

Then, the Cube is a child of this object. If you modify the localPosition or localRotation of the cube it will work as you want it.

The Cube is a child of the Marker scene, its global position and rotation will be a combination of the position and rotation of its parent with its local position and rotation (this is standard 3DEngine / SceneGraph behaviour).

Comment: So that means we are unable to do this ?

Comment: On the contrary, it is possible and quite straight forward. What I am saying is that you need to have an empty object as the AR Tracked object and then manipulate the child objects.

Comment: I am unable to follow these steps. Could you please show me how to do it?. It would be very helpful.

Comment: if you follow any of the ARTookit examples, they are organized that way. I have edited the response with a screenshot.

Comment: I will try this ThankYou :)